# Dockerfile to run .net core console app on Linux (which is not self contained)

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, console-application, dockerfile

I have a .net Core 2.1 console application and I want to build it into a docker container that will be deployed to Linux (Alpine).

If this had an output on windows of an exe (and was self-contained of course).  My docker file might look like this:

```
COPY  /output/ /bin/
CMD ["/bin/sample.exe"]
```

As I want to make this a portable app (and have .net Core Runtime on the Linux box already), should my docker file look like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime

COPY  /output/ /bin/
CMD ["dotnet", "/bin/sample.dll"]
```

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft has a dotnet docker [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples) repository. Their Dockerfile looks like to following:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime
COPY /output /bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/bin/dotnetapp.dll"]
```

They also have a [alpine based example](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/blob/master/dotnetapp-prod-alpine-preview/Dockerfile) of a Dockerfile

For more information on [Entrypoint / CMD](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/)